# Developer Sandbox Refresh Status Stopped

Tags: sandbox, sandbox-refresh, winter16

**UPDATE**: Dev sandbox refresh is completed after 5 hour in stopped phase. But I'd still like to now what causes this.

Today I tried to refresh a developer sandbox in our org. First it was in queue as usual but then after some time I saw it has stopped. I've searched for the cause but did not find anything.

why would a developer sandbox refresh status change to stopped? It seems like there is nothing to do about it. No button, nothing available to change status.

And I've noticed lately even developer sandbox refreshes takes too much time. I think it became slow in Winter 16. Before Winter 16 I remember 10-30 minutes refreshes for normal org with some classes/triggers but now same orgs with no changes takes at least 4-5 hours even sometime more than 10 hours to refresh.

[image: Screenshot of page]

Comment: Same issue here on NA31. Dev sandbox refresh just shows 'Stopped' with no indication on why and no actions to do anything about it.

Comment: Also seeing this on NA 29

Comment: Same here on NA 20.

Comment: Possibly related to this [Known Issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000javvAAA)?

Comment: It seems like after 5 hour in stopped phase developer sandbox refresh is completed. I' still don't know the cause though

Comment: Same issue here.  We just initiated a Developer sandbox refresh and it almost immediately went to 'Stopped' status.  We'll see if it ever finishes the refresh...

Comment: Same deal on NA24.

Comment: Even i am facing similar issue. Developer sandbox creation shows status as stopped with 0% progress and Org Id. gives pending. Status is the same from past hours. Any workaround and reason of this occurrence?

Comment: Now  it's "Pending".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue. It was resolved a few days ago

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p30000000javlAAA

Comment: I'm still facing this issue. More than 4 hours have passed and the sandbox isn't refreshed even now.